# doctrine2 attribute doesn't exist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

this is my entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="Animal")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks 
*/
class Animal {

    /**
    * @var integer $id
    * 
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")     
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var localizedcontent $lctitle
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="localizedcontent",fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lcTitle", referencedColumnName="pkId", nullable=false)
    */
    private $lctitle;

    /**
    * @var localizedcontent $lcdescription
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="localizedcontent",fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lcDescription", referencedColumnName="pkId", nullable=false)
    */
    private $lcdescription;

    /**
    * @ORM\PostLoad
    */
    public function postLoad(){
      $lct = $this->lctitle;
      $lcd = $this->lcdescription;          
    }
```

This is my dql:

```
SELECT a,lct FROM Animal JOIN e.lctitle lct WHERE a.id=:id
```

When i'm starting xdebug, it tells me that lcdescription is a proxy object and lctitle doesn't exists. I don't know why.
I think the postLoad event is too early because the localizedcontent isn't loaded at this moment, right? Is there an other listener for reading the value of lctitle in relation to the Animal Object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine always returns proxies. These classes inherit from the entity-classes. It might help if you declare your relations protected instead of private.

```
/**
* @var localizedcontent $lctitle
*
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="localizedcontent",fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lcTitle", referencedColumnName="pkId", nullable=false)
*/
protected $lctitle;
```

or you could write a getter and call this one in your post-load function

```
public function getLctitle() {
    return $this->lctitle;
}

public function getLcdescription() {
    return $this->lcdescription;
}

/**
* @ORM\PostLoad
*/
public function postLoad(){
  $lct = $this->getLctitle();
  $lcd = $this->getLcdescription();          
}
```

Comment: The postLoad Method is inside the Animal Entity so i donÄt need to use a getter and when i declare lctitle to protected, then i get a fatal error that means i must set id to protected or weaker. I'm very confused.

Comment: You're right. Have a look at the generated proxy-class maybe the postLoad method is overwritten. I have only used protected variables in my entities and it works. Maybe if you change all your private methods and vars to protected it works.